# Okta endpoint call throws ConnectionTimed out exception

Tags: okta

I am getting okta login page and when it authenticates, i am calling token endpoint to get the tokens it works super fine from my system. But when I deploy it in integration system, its throwing me **java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)** error. I am assuming it could be because of firewall issue.

Is my assumption is right? If yes, What kind of details i have to provide to open firewall?
Do I need add/check something else?

Below is from my okta server log. After I am getting exception.
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to your deployment environment and try to `curl` to your authZ server `/token` endpoint with a GET request. You will immediately see if there is an issue with the connection. It may be as simple as providing a proxy for the connection, or something else. Your network team should help you, when you tell them Okta endpoint, you are trying to reach

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the below when I run curl command in my deployment env, but the same connecting in my local system.


curl -v -X GET "https://XXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/aus1yzsEX1d7/v1/token/"
* About to connect() to XXX.oktapreview.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 34.364.87.17...
* Connection timed out

I guess I have to raise firewall open. Please advice otherwise.

Comment: But similar /authorize endpoint curl works fine local and returning response. The same curl command is timedout in integration environment, but via the application the /authorize endpoint works fine returns okta login page. Is it something different?

Comment: hard to tell, but failing `curl` is indicating network connectivity issue, so I'd talk to your networking admin team

Comment: networking team opened the firewall and it solved issue. Thank you.